# Generate A Self Signed Certificate Signed By An Root Certificate in Powershell

Tags: powershell, encryption

How To Generate A Self Signed Certificate Signed By An Root Certificate using New-SelfSignedCertificate, I Have A Root Certificate I Just Want to Know How To Use -Signer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already figured out that you need to use the `-Signer` parameter. Just ensure that you have the private key for the certificate you want to use to sign the new certificate. So basically you can only use certificates from the `Personal` store ("My" in PowerShell).

Example:

```
# find a suitable certificate to use as root
ls Cert:\CurrentUser\My\
$root = ls Cert:\CurrentUser\My\c123a6f16a5f165161a1...  # use the thumbprint of one of your certificates

# create a certificate which is signed with your chosen root certificate
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName test.local -Signer $root -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\My\
```

Comment: Thanks, @Swonkie So Now It Shows The Signer But It Says "The Integrity of this certificate cannot be guaranteed. The Certificate may be corrupted or may have been altered"